# Is there a fast way to convert this type of data to a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, performance, dictionary

I have the following DataFrame where in the first column I have a gene pathway ID, and in the second column a list of genes involved in that patway:

| gene pathway ID | gene ID |
| --- | --- |
| ID1 | gene1,gene2,gene3 |
| ID2 | gene2,gene4,gene6 |
| ID3 | gene1,gene3,gene6 |
| ... | .... |

To speed up some processes I would like to create a dictionary where the keys are the genes, and values are lists of pathway id:

```
dict = {gene1:[ID1,ID3], gene2:[ID1,ID2], gene3:[ID1,ID3], ...}
```

Is there a fast way to create such dictionary? For now the only approach I used it's way too slow.

Comment: Can you post your approach? it doesnt seems hard code to do it (iterate list and check key and value exists etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what solution you tried. I can propose this one. The result is the dict you ask for:

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    genes = row['gene ID'].split(',')
    for g in genes:
        result[g].append(row['gene pathway ID'])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately I cannot use spit() since the columns with genes ID contains lists and not strings

Comment: even better, just use the list, no need to split (just remove .split() and it should be fine)

Comment: thank you, using directly the list worked for me

Answer (score 1):

In case of

```
df =
  gene pathway ID     gene ID
0  ID1  [gene1, gene2, gene3]
1  ID2  [gene2, gene4, gene6]
2  ID3  [gene1, gene3, gene6]
```

you could use

```
from collections import defaultdict

genes_dict = defaultdict(list)
for i, genes in df.itertuples(index=False):
    for gene in genes:
        genes_dict[gene].append(i)
```

In case of

```
df = 
  gene pathway ID  gene ID
0  ID1  gene1,gene2,gene3
1  ID2  gene2,gene4,gene6
2  ID3  gene1,gene3,gene6
```

you could try

```
from collections import defaultdict

genes_dict = defaultdict(list)
for i, genes in df.itertuples(index=False):
    for gene in genes.split(","):
        genes_dict[gene].append(i)
```

Comment: Thank you, in my case the first solution is the one I need since I have lists and not strings for the genes ID